# Jsoup to crawle pages to my local drive

Tags: html, search, download, jsoup, web-crawler

Im working on a search engine, I want to have a jsoup web crawler to get the pages from a web site and store them those pages in my local hard drive, C:\tmp for example. Can you help me with that

Thanks ;)

Comment: Why use Jsoup? Download the web page as HTML file and store where you want?

Comment: Yeah but i don't want to do it manually, i want the jsoup to download the pages from one web site in one time

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using jsoup.

```
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").get();
        String html = doc.html();
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:/tmp/wiki.html"));
        out.write(html);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It would produce a file named `wiki.html` containing wikipedia's main page in the directory `c:/tmp/`.